# parameters passed when clicking a point on a NVD3 line chart or a slice in a pie chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have just started using NVD3 for drawing simple charts such as line/pie/bar and such.

I would like to add some mouse interactivity to these charts but cannot find specific documentation nor example code:

1. allow user to click a specific line point, pie slice, bar component
2. receive in my program notification of the click with details of the series and point/data row pertinent to the click.

E.g., if I drew sales versus years, I would like user to be able to drill down to sales of a particular year. The line graph onclick example I have seen here are way too coarse for such detailed interaction.

Is there a relevant page(s) that documents the mouse click specifications for these types of charts?

Is it even possible with NVD3?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure nvd3 offers that functionally (it might!). If you're just wanting to show standard 'line/bar/pie' charts that drill down, dc.js might be what you're looking for http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/

Comment: @Adam this looks quite interactive and worthy of exploring. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here you can see the plunker example ,may be you can get some help .
this example is for the pie chart drill down using angularjs and Nvd3 charting lib.

http://plnkr.co/edit/UjOP0k5Jo3OvQ6A79Qv9?p=preview